# Huawei HG8245Q2 connected with other router in bridge mode and WiFi with internet access

Tags: networking, router, bridge

I have Huawei HG8245Q2 router with GPON WAN and 4 ethernet ports and powerful WiFi module.

Behind this router I have second (Mikrotik) router and a L2TP server on it.

Unfortunately - Huawei router in "normal" configuration does not allow me to have L2TP server behind it (I tried with DMZ with no success and there is no option like "VPN-passthru" like I saw in some other routers).

I called my ISP tech support and consultant changed Huawei configuration and my WAN was "transparently" connected LAN1 port (bridged WAN<->LAN1?). I changed Mikrotik configuration to PPPoE and my L2TP server worked.

However that change had side effect - other interfaces (LAN2, LAN3, LAN4, WiFi) on Huawei were not connected with internet.

I had to restore Huawei to factory settings (to undo changes done by ISP consultant), switch Mikrotik back to normal (without PPPoE), my L2TP is not working again.

Unfortunately I have not checked how remaining ports work (LAN2, LAN3, LAN4, WiFi), or more precisely whether they are bridged with each other. Also I can't reconfigure it back to "transparent" (bridge WAN<->LAN1?) mode myself.

I don't want to ruin good relations with my ISP by calling too many times with a request to change the configuration (to check if it would work or not) which theoretically does not have to be made at all because my contract does not provide for such changes and I don't understand everything completely. So I'm asking here before I do that again and to improve my knowledge.

---

This is how I understand how it works:

L2TP working, WiFi without internet

[image]

L2TP not working, WiFi internet OK

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

---

**Question 1:**

**Is it possible to connect one of Mikrotik LAN ports to one of remaining Huawei ports (LAN2 for example) and configure in such a way that Mikrotik would be a gateway for Huawei WiFi?** If it is - how can I do that?

I have idea like this (*I'm not networking expert*):

- connect Mikrotik ETH2 to Huawei LAN2
- remove ETH2 from bridge on Mikrotik (now all ETH interfaces except WAN are bridged)
- set IP address 10.0.0.250 on ETH2 on Mikrotik to connect it to Huawei network (Huawei has 10.0.0.1 IP)
- turn off DHCP on Huawei because it does not allow to configure diffrent gateway
- add DHCP server on Mikrotik and somehow make it work for Huawei WiFi and assign 10.0.1.0/24 addresses and 10.0.1.1 gateway (Mikrotik)

Does it make sense?

**Question 2:** (extra)

What is going on with LAN2, LAN3, LAN4, WiFi interfaces when Huawei is in "transparent" mode (bridge WAN->LAN1?). Are they still bridged with each other?

---